# Outbox for routing slip in statemachine?

Tags: masstransit, routing-slip

In one of my statemachine actions I create a routing slip to carry out a series of commands. This is done by calling

```
_busControl.Execute(routingSlip);
```

But sometimes the saga commit fails due to concurrency issues. Is there a "outbox" like mechanism to defer sending the routing slip to the bus until the saga is committed successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the outbox to defer sends:

http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/exceptions.html#outbox

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("input-queue", e =>
{
    e.UseInMemoryOutbox();

    e.StateMachineSaga(...);
});
```

You will, however, need to execute the routing slip using the `ConsumeContext` in the state machine event handler, and not using `_busControl`. `IBus` or `IBusControl` should never be used inside a consumer. The [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/producers.html#send) has more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working with `var consumerContext = ctx.CreateConsumeContext();
            await consumerContext.Execute(routingSlip);` where ctx is the BehaviorContext